Drag and Drop is in reverse order
Ubuntu 24.04
When I drag and drop files they get placed in reverse order - Z-A
Is there any way to make it alphabetical? A-Z

From / to what app's do you drag and drop ?

Dragging media from Gnome Files to a media player (MPV, Celluloid, VLC, Strawberry Music Player).
It happens on everything -
Files to Terminal -
Dragging music from Strawberry to the terminal even

That's strange, dragging from files (Nautilus) indeed drop the file-list in reverse order as it was at source. Dragging and dropping from Rythmbox doenb't. So the problem must be in Nautilus.

Yes. This seems to be yet another dnd problem with Nautilus. Thunar file manager must be working OK though. Please report the bug at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/

Although not documented, the release of Nautilus 46.1 seems to solve this problem.

Please upgrade or install using:
$ sudo apt install nautilus


Verify you have version 46.1 using the "hamburger menu" (≣) → About Files.

Retry.


I have tested the above on three different systems.
